# How to make timer fire in a recurring manner

Tags: c#, .net, windows, multithreading, timer

I have a timer which I want to expire **every** Monday at 5pm.  When testing the application, as soon as it reaches 5pm on a Monday, my task is fired as it is supposed to.

However, when I change the system date and time to the following week at 5pm, the task does not fire.  This is my code:

```
Timer timer = new Timer(callback, application, timeToEnd, TimeSpan.FromDays(7));
```

I have a feeling that it has something to do with the `TimeSpan.FromDays(7)` part. Any ideas?

Comment: Which timer are you using?

Comment: @Servy - System.Threading.Timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're now in trouble. We asked the framework to notify you after `x days, y hours, z minutes`. So timer will fire exactly after what time you told it to.

I know this is not the right way to go, but this will work.

```
SystemEvents.TimeChanged += SystemEvents_TimeChanged;

static void SystemEvents_TimeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer.Dispose();//Dispose your previous timer
    SetTimerAgain();//Call the method which sets the timer again. you're done
}
```

I recommend "Windows Scheduled Tasks", but for some reason you can't so here is the way to go.

Also you could run a periodic timer as @giammin suggested.

```
TimerCallback callback = (state) =>
{      
    var now = DateTime.Now; 
    if(now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday 
     && now.TimeOfDay.Hours == 17 && now.TimeOfDay.Minutes == 0)
    {
        MyMethod();
    }
};

Timer timer = new Timer(callback, application, 0, 10000);//10seconds
```

With the latter approach you should defend yourself from calling the method again and again for the same day.

Comment: I am only changing the system time for testing purposes however - in the deployed environment, the system time will not be changed.

Comment: To clarify - if I had to leave the code as it is, and NOT change the system time, would the timer fire the next Monday? I am only changing the system date and time to try to simulate a week passing, just to test it

Comment: Yes it should work without any problem. May be you get a problem when there is a race you set time exactly to `monday 5pm`. That time it may not work properly. Otherwise it should work.

Comment: @DotNET Yes, and that mechanism is not an appropriate way of testing this mechanism.  It will fire in a week.  Changing the system time won't affect it at all; it will fire in one week regardless.

Comment: Thanks to you too @Servy

Comment: @DotNET Updated answer for checking periodically as giammin suggested. You can choose to use any :)

Comment: The system time almost certainly *will* be changed periodically. For example, Daylight Saving Time changes and NTP updates. The latter, however, will likely be in the range of a few seconds (if that).

Answer (score 2):

This is not a good use for a `Timer`.  You should create a console application that does what you want, then schedule it with Windows Scheduler or a 3rd party scheduling tool.

Otherwise, the safer thing to do is to set the timer to run at a *short* interval (1 minute?) and check the system clock to see if it needs to run or not (e.g. is it within 1 minute of 5:00?)

Comment: I agree with you, however this is not my code and thus I cannot re-write everything.

Comment: You don't have to re-write everything - just create a console app that calls the relevant _existing_ code once and schedule that to run at the desired time.  `Timer` is designed to run code on an _interval_ not at a specified _time_.  However, I've added some additional possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

None of the timers depend on the system time.

Changing the clock will not affect `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, `System.Timers.Timer`, or `System.Threading.Timer`.

If you need to handle those situation you have to rely on [SystemEvents.TimeChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.timechanged%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Otherwise you can check periodically for `DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek .Monday`

Comment: Interesting. That would explain it - but in that case, where do the Timer classes get their time from? As it is based on the system clock for sure, since my PC's clock is 5 minutes ahead - and the timers still fire at 5pm on my clock

Comment: @DotNET it uses processor ticks not windows date. It is due to how you inizialize the timer using DateTime.Now

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. So theoretically there is nothing wrong with my code, and if I had to wait a week, the task should fire again?

Comment: @DotNET yes but it is better to check for DateTime.Now for so long periods instead of using timer becouse in addition to time changes there could be daylightsaving

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to rely on an external service like the Window Task Scheduler you will have to create a timer that fires at regular intervals (say every minute) and checks the current time, and if the current time has passed the next expiration time it actually performs the desired action (including setting up the next expiration time).

Performing a time check every minute should not be a problem unless you are running on a low powered device.

Moving the clock forward a week is a pretty extreme measure but daylight savings can also move the clock and in particular on virtual machines you may have some unexpected clock drift. This is why checking the current time at regular intervals most of the time is better than just setting a timer to fire at some distant future time.

Speaking of daylight savings you need to handle the situation where the clock moves backward one hour in case your want to perform you activity in that interval.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a timer that will fire at a specific time, use a [Waitable Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687012%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Unfortunately, the .NET libraries don't have a wrapper for that timer. I wrote one some time back for an article. The article is no longer available online, but you can download the source code from http://mischel.com/pubs/waitabletimer.zip.

That said, it sounds to me what you have is a [catnap program](http://blog.mischel.com/2013/02/01/programs-are-not-cats/). Do as others have suggested and make it a simple console app that you control with Scheduled Tasks.